# How to make jquery scrollLeft smoother

Tags: jquery

I am new to JQuery . I wish to know if the following code can be changed in a way so that smoother scrolling is enabled. The code works but I want the scrolling to be more like sliding

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div.left").click(function(){
          let pos = parseFloat($("div.icon_bar").scrollLeft()) + 55;
          $("div").scrollLeft(pos);
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try jQuery animate:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'div.left', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('div.icon_bar').animate({
        scrollLeft: $("div.icon_bar").offset().left + 55;
    }, 500);
});
```

Otherwise, you can experiment with css `scroll-behavior`:

```css
div.icon_bar {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Comment: If this answer is useful for You, please mark it as correct.

Comment: The jquery code you provided is not working . Sorry for the late reply. Thank you very much for trying to help

Comment: publish your html pls

Answer (score 0):

```
      'right' is the id of the button I click to scroll. 'icon_bar' is the id of the div that I have the horizontal scrollbar attached to. This worked for me. Hope it helps someone. 

      $(function() { $("#right").on('click', function() {


            $("#icon_bar").animate({ scrollLeft: "50px" }, 900);


       });

       });
```